# List elements JSON recursive with SelectToken JObject

Tags: c#, json.net

How can I list all my "children" elements recursively using the select token method?

Actual JSON Structure

```
{
  "component": "stackpanel",
  "id": "001",
  "children": [
    {
      "component": "label",
      "id": "001.1",
      "text": "foobar123",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "component": "textbox",
      "id": "001.2",
      "text": "",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "component": "stackpanel",
      "id": "001.3",
      "children": [
        {
          "component": "textbox",
          "id": "001.3.1",
          "text": "subfoobar",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My code Implementation

`var listChildrenElements= jsonElement.SelectTokens("$..*").OfType<JObject>();`

Result I wait for the select token:

```
[
 {
  "component": "stackpanel",
  "id": "001",
  "children": [...]
 },
 {
   "component": "label",
   "id": "001.1",
   "text": "foobar123",
   "children": []
 },
 {
   "component": "textbox",
   "id": "001.2",
   "text": "",
   "children": []
 },
 {
    "component": "stackpanel",
    "id": "001.3",
    "children": [...]
  },
  {
    "component": "textbox",
    "id": "001.3.1",
    "text": "subfoobar",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

Is it possible to make the list according to the expected model example that I hope to receive? This in a recursive way because there can be numerous elements within the "children"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<JObject> SelectHierarchy(IEnumerable<JObject> source)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return item;

            var childResults = SelectHierarchy(item["children"].Children().Cast<JObject>());
            foreach (var childItem in childResults)
            {
                yield return childItem;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then call it on `IEnumerable` with your root item:

```
var list = SelectHierarchy(new [] {jobject});
```

Comment: This method worked perfectly, but if I make any changes to any element within the IEnumerable (var listChildrenElements) it will not be reflected in my JObject? This filter idea would be to help me treat each element of json

Comment: If you change any element at `listChildrenElements` changes will be reflected at you `JObject`. If I understand right, you trying simplify access to nested items for modify them?